# Differrent results in different compilers c++

Tags: c++

I have created the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a,b,mod, a1,b1;
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    if(a >= b){
        mod = a % b;
    } else {
        mod = b % a;
    }

    
    if(mod == 0){
        std::cout << a;
    } else {
        while(a1 != 0 && b1 != 0){

        a1 = a % mod;
        b1 = b % mod;
        --mod;
    }
    std::cout << mod + 1;

}
   
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested with the following input: `25 27` and got result `1` (as expected).
But in another compiler I got result `3` and unfortunately I don't have an access to testing with another compiler(only the final result). I don't know why and where the behaviour of my program is inconsistent.

Comment: Ask yourself: In `while(a1 != 0 && b1 != 0)`, what are the initial values of `a1` and `b1`?

Comment: Dear compiler vendors: please make `-Wall` or equivalent the default.

Comment: @jarmod not enough, the warnings will get ignored. -Wall -Werror is needed

Comment: Example of using a common compiler to detect errors like this (and a link to a tool you can use to test out your code with a smurfload of different compilers): https://godbolt.org/z/jb14vh8xP Note all of the compiler options I have turned on, `-O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined`, to tell the compiler to be anally retentive in it's quest for mistakes. Only the standard flag, `-std=c++17`, isn't an option contributing to checking for potential errors.

Comment: @pm100 an optimize flag was needed as well. https://godbolt.org/z/3884975Pa

Comment: @user4581301 i just mean in general, the defaults should be -Wall -Werror, imagine how many SO posts would disappear

Comment: @pm100 Right now I'm more imagining the number of SO posts it would *generate* by people that seem utterly dysfunction to spend 5 seconds searching for an error, but will take 5 *minutes* to write a duplicate question about said-same. Don't misunderstand. I still believe you're right; that should be the default regardless, but oh my word, the deluge that wouldst befall us. One way or another, they're gonna come.

Comment: Understood and agreed. But if we let people find out that this programming thing's not as hard as it looks when you use the tools right, we might face greater iob pressure.

Comment: I just wished the compiler vendors would turn off the VLA's by default.  That would cut down by a significant margin the number of questions asked by newbies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a1 and b1 is not initialized by correct numbers. If you set correct initial version, you should get consistent behavior.